# Getting null point exceptions when using methods in other activites - android

Tags: java, android, methods

So I am trying to access a method in another activity, basically to check if there's new data in the chat and if there is, it shows a toast. But I'm getting an error whenever I try to use this, or Activity.this in any function. If I try to use context, it works but rest all functions start giving null.

Here's what I did

DoTheTask.class

```
Chat c = new Chat();
c.Mymethod("true",id);
```

Chat.class

```
public void Mymethod(String fd, String id)
    {
        if(fd.equals("true")){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Chat is open", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Here the "this" inside toast is giving NPE, I passed context with the method but I want to use this because I have many other functions required which work only with this or activity.this and not context (they give errors)

Comment: what does makeText method return?

Comment: this can never be null.  You're wrong on what's giving the npe.

Comment: @GabeSechan                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: @SubhranshuKumar this can never be null.  Its the current instance.  For this to be null it would need to be called on null-  which would have caused an NPE 1 level higher in the callstack.